# Di compile error while installing Magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, command-line

Hi i am installing Magento 2.3.5 but getting error on di:compile command

```
MiBErrors during compilation:
Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Model\Apiconnector\EngagementCloudAddressBookApi
Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Logger\Logger. Actual type: \Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Helper\File; File:
/home/stylekulcom/public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-

extension/Model/Apiconnector/EngagementCloudAddressBookApi.php

Total Errors Count: 1
```

[image]

Comment: did you tried removing generated folder manually?

Comment: Yes I removed it but still getting same error

Comment: then you should check that helper file

Comment: try replacing the code with the code am posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your magento module with this one

https://github.com/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension

Comment: Let me try this code.

Comment: same error with this code as well.

Comment: https://github.com/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension  try replacing your complete module with this

Comment: BTW this file does not exists in this module dotmailer-magento2-extension/Model/Apiconnector/EngagementCloudAddressBookApi.php

Comment: I have deleted magento module added this one and it worked . Thanks man for your support.

Comment: haha dirty solution

Comment: Whats the proper way to do this now?

Comment: its good actually this module is official release so they might have fix previous bugs anyways i had updated my ans may be it will be helpful for someone

Answer (score 1):

Run this commands, deleting files/module manually not a good approach.

```
  composer remove dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension   
  composer require dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension -vvv
  mv generated generated_dotfix
  php bin/magento setup:upgrade
  php bin/magento setup:di:compile
  php bin/magento s:s:d -s
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same issue on Magento 2.3.5, above solution hasnt worked even when I disable the dotmailer-magento2-extension

```
public_html$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Compilation was started.
Interception cache generation... 6/8 [=====================>------]  75% 44 secs 512.0 MiBErrors during compilation:
        Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Model\Apiconnector\EngagementCloudAddressBookApi
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Logger\Logger. Actual type: \Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Helper\File; File:
/public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Model/Apiconnector/EngagementCloudAddressBookApi.php

Total Errors Count: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands on magento root:

```
rm -rf composer.lock
rm -rf generated/*
rm -rf vendor/*
composer update
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d
php bin/magento c:f
php bin/magento c:c
```

Answer (score 0):

1)delete the older version files  at /vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension

2)download the latest version at https://github.com/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension

3)extract and upload the latest version files to /vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension

re-execute the commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```